# Facing issue in creating .exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, byte, capstone

I have python script which extract the bytes code from any types of file and in script i am using capstone library
I'm trying to create .exe file for my script using pyinstaller library using this command

```
pyinstaller --onefile Ectract.py
```

but when i run Extract.exe file i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Extract.py", line 6, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimode2_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module File "capstone\__init__.py", line 428, in <module>
ImportError: ERROR: fail to load the dynamic library.
[4748] Failed to execute script 'Extract' due to unhandled exception!
```

After that I used this command to create .exe but getting same error

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Lib/site-packages/capstone/lib/capstone.dll;." Extract.py
```

Please help with this issue

Extract.py

```
import os
import random
import string
import time
import shutil
from capstone import*

def extract_hex_from_file(file_path, output_folder, bytes_per_line):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        random_name = generate_random_name() + '.bytes'
        output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, random_name)
        with open(output_file, 'w') as output:
            address = 0x00401000  # Start address
            while True:
                chunk = f.read(bytes_per_line)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                hex_bytes = ' '.join(f"{byte:02X}" for byte in chunk)
                output.write(f"{address:08X} {hex_bytes}\n")
                address += bytes_per_line
    return random_name[:-6]

def generate_random_name(length=20):
    letters_and_digits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters_and_digits) for _ in range(length))

def check_disk_space(output_folder):
    free_space = shutil.disk_usage(output_folder).free
    return free_space

def process_files(file_path, output_folder, bytes_per_line, arch):
    try:
        generated_name = extract_hex_from_file(file_path, output_folder, bytes_per_line)
        if check_disk_space(output_folder) < os.path.getsize(file_path):
            print(f"Not enough space available to process file: {file_path}. Skipping.")
            return None
        else:
            disassemble_file(os.path.join(output_folder, generated_name + '.bytes'), output_folder, arch)
            return generated_name
    except PermissionError:
        print(f"{file_path}. .")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing file: {file_path}. Error: {str(e)}")
        return None

def extract_hex_from_folder(folder_path, output_folder, bytes_per_line=16, arch='x86'):
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    file_paths = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file_name in files:
            file_paths.append(os.path.join(root, file_name))
    start_time = time.time()
    for file_path in file_paths:
        process_files(file_path, output_folder, bytes_per_line, arch)
    end_time = time.time()
    total_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Total execution time: {total_time} seconds")

def disassemble_file(filename, output_folder, arch):
    arch_map = {
        'x86': CS_ARCH_X86,
        'x86-64': CS_ARCH_X86,
        'arm': CS_ARCH_ARM,
    }
    md = Cs(arch_map[arch], CS_MODE_64 if arch == 'x86-64' else CS_MODE_ARM)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        code = f.read()
    disassembly_output = ""
    for instr in md.disasm(code, 0x1000):
        disassembly_output += f"0x{instr.address:x}:\t{instr.mnemonic}\t{instr.op_str}\n"
    section_rva = 0x1000
    section_size = 0x100
    disassembly_output += "\nDisassembly of specified code section:\n"
    for instr in md.disasm(code[section_rva:section_rva+section_size], section_rva):
        disassembly_output += f"0x{instr.address:x}:\t{instr.mnemonic}\t{instr.op_str}\n"

    base_name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))
    output_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, base_name + '.asm')
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(disassembly_output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_path = '/path/'
    output_folder = '/path/'
    bytes_per_line = 16
    arch = 'x86'
    extract_hex_from_folder(folder_path, output_folder, bytes_per_line, arch)
```

Comment: "Failed to execute script 'Extract' due to unhandled exception!"

The question is, is this your exception or the exception of the pyinstaller?
I would try and check the code if there is something unhandled just for your safety. If yes you can at least eliminate this possibility.

Comment: please check questions details script is there

Comment: From first view I would maybe tried to encapsule every `with open()` into a try except, what if file is not there (or path does not exist). This is only thing that somehow takes my attention... Otherwise everything seems fine, at least for me.

Comment: And please be aware that Python script with installed libraries and somehow complicated ones (for example tKinter) are harder to build into .exe. it Causes a lot of troubles to make it done. Maybe consider using it via a batch. This way you would also eliminate this issue.